# VBA Pulse Animation in PowerPoint 2013 using Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I hope I'm in the right SE. The posts I found directed me to post here.

BLUF: I am trying to use an if/else statement to apply/remove the pulse animation on a specific object in PowerPoint.

Background: The code lives on an excel document because I am using that as a simple basic figurative firewall to keep employees from messing with slides. I want a live updating document that pushes info into a running PowerPoint slide and updates the text as to the status of specific site status (up or down). I made a simple up/down button that only changes between UP/DN in the cell and feeds that into other cells to determine what to do with the data. THen a macro button runs the code and updates the text on the PowerPoint.

Good news: Everything works great (aside from the animation). The text changes (words and color) while the PowerPoint is running and locking the Excel document prevents employees messing with any settings.

Main part of code in question:

```
For Each c In Sheet1.Range("a2:a" & Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

shapeslide = Sheet1.Range("a" & c.Row)
shapename = Sheet1.Range("b" & c.Row)
shapetext = (Sheet1.Range("c" & c.Row).Text)
friendlyname = Sheet1.Range("d" & c.Row)
pPreso.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext

If (friendlyname = "DN") Then
pPreso.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

'The porttion below worked, but it is not animation (not as cool)
'pPreso.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.PresetTextEffect = 4
'pPreso.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffectFormat = msoAnimEffectBoldFlash

Else
pPreso.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)

End If

Next c
```

The for statement runs through the cells where I call out the specific slide, shape, and shape text. The friendlyname is a repeat to run the IF/Else.

If I change the status to DN, it turns red, then if I change it to UP, it turns green.

I was able to get an animation applied using this code in the If/Else:

```
Dim oeff As Effect
Dim osld As Shape
Set osld = ppapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename)
With pPreso.Slides(shapeslide)
Set oeff = .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=.Shapes(shapename),_ effectID:=msoAnimEffectBoldFlash, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious)
With oeff
.Timing.RepeatDuration = 25
End With
End With
```

The main problem is that (understandably) it continually applies the animation, because there is obviously no check to see if applied in this code. Secondly, when I tried to introduce oeff.delete, it just left the animation and then applied a non animation to all others marked as "UP" in the animation pane of PowerPoint.

So, 2 things:

1. Is there an option to apply the pulse animation? I couldn't find it in the msoAnimEffect library area.
2. Does anyone have an elegant way of turning an animation on or off using this method I created or will I need to figure out a way to set flags, read those flags, then somehow incorporate those into the If/Else statement?

Here is a pic of the Excel Doc:

[image: ExcelExample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After conferring with a friend, I was able to get things running, and added a little extra spice myself.

Here is the code that got the animation working:

```
'New Variables
Dim timestamptext
Dim oeff As PowerPoint.Effect
Dim oshp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim osld As PowerPoint.Slide
'Add Effect
Set oshp = pApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename)
With pPreso.Slides(shapeslide)
Set oeff = .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=Shapes(shapename),effectID:_
=msoAnimEffectFlashBulb,trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
With oeff
'Lasts for a 60 second slide
.Timing.RepeatDuration = 60
End With
End With
```

Then the part that gets rid of those animations (thanks to CM!)

```
'Delete Effect
Set osld = pPreso.Slides(shapeslide)
'The 28 is only because I have 28 other animations happening that should stay
If osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count>28 Then
For i = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 29 Step -1
Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence(i)
If oeff.Shape.Name Like shapename Then
oeff.Delete
End If
Next i
End If
```

Hope this helps some folks out there.

As a bonus, I added a timestamp to the slide so that I could see when the last time the status was updated using this code (the object is text box 28 on all slides and the timestamp is the "NOW()" function in Excel in cell H25):

Note: this is inside the Main For loop, but outside the main If/Else ="DN"

```
timestamptext = (Sheet1.Range("H"&25).Text)
pPreso.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes("Text Box 28").TextEffect.Text = timestamptext
```